# How to get specific data from JSON OR URL in Android?

Tags: android, json, phpmyadmin

I want to get particular user data from PHP MySql in Android. Here is my URL (xxx//xxxxxxx/client_vendor_mgmt/subcategory.php?cat_id=2) and
here is the URL data in json:

```
[
    {
        "subcat_id": "1",
        "subcat_code": "cell1",
        "subcat_name": "cell",
        "cat_id": "2",
        "subcat_created_date": "0000-00-00",
        "subcat_isactive": "Y",
        "subcat_updated_date": "0000-00-00"
    },
    {
        "subcat_id": "2",
        "subcat_code": "cell2",
        "subcat_name": "tv",
        "cat_id": "2",
        "subcat_created_date": "0000-00-00",
        "subcat_isactive": "Y",
        "subcat_updated_date": "0000-00-00"
    }
]
```

I want to get all the record of "cat_id":"2". How can I get this record?

Comment: did you try to google "how to parse JSON in Android"?

Comment: you already have all record with cat_id==2

Comment: where you want to show this data?

Comment: @Rohan Pawar:- I want to show this data into Spinner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code

```
try {
            JSONArray array=new JSONArray("yourJsonString");

            JSONArray sortedArray = new JSONArray();
            for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++)
            {
                JSONObject obj=array.getJSONObject(i);
                if(obj.getString("cat_id").equalsIgnoreCase("2"))
                {
                    sortedArray.put(obj);
                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: :- In your JSONArray array=new JSONArray("yourJsonString"); = what shoul i put in this place of "yourJsonString" ?

Comment: the data you got from webservice

Answer (score 0):

Use a json Parser Library like `Gson` and `Jackson`.

Answer (score 0):

```
        JSONArray ja=new JSONArray("yourResponsString");
        JSONObject jo=ja.getJSONObject(0);
        String cat_id=jo.getString("cat_id");
        if(cat_id.equals("2")){

            // this is your object
        }
```

Comment: may need to import: import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONArray;

Answer (score 0):

```
 JSONArray ja=new JSONArray("yourResponsString");
    for(int i=0;i<ja.length;i++)
{
JSONObject obj = ja.getJSONObject(i);
    String cat_id=obj.getString("cat_id");
    if(cat_id.equals("2")){

        // this is your object
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.